# Which one is correct? "offers her" or "offers she"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> The man offers her to drink coffee.
>
> The man offers she drinks coffee.

Comment: What is your preferred option, and why?

Comment: @CowperKettle I asked, is both correct grammatically? and are they equal?

Comment: Neither is grammatical. But just asking for proofreading is off topic.

Comment: @JasonBassford instead of saying off topic and voting down, answer and explain why they are incorrect.

Comment: This is proofreading, according to the way the site works. This is the definition given of the particular vote to close: "Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about; if that's not possible, see websites for proofreading instead."

Comment: You can't just ask if something is grammatical or not—or which of X choices is *the right one*. This isn't a proofreading or writing service. Questions and answers need to be useful for all other people who come here.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't think so. Because when I want to send a post I click on "Ask Question" not "Post your useful content".

Comment: @M.Afrashteh: Sorry, but that superficial understanding of the website is entirely wrong. The site software will block you from asking questions if too many are closed or downvoted (that is, if they are generally not useful). We do not want useless posts.

Comment: @M.Afrashteh - Sure, there is an “Ask Question” button, but have you looked through the [“Asking” section](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/asking) of the [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) yet? Please do. I recommend starting with [“How do I ask a good question?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Please avoid asking scant “Which one is correct?” questions in the future, and strive to write questions like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167274) instead. See [_Details, please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439) on meta as well.

Comment: Also, your comment says, _" I asked, is both correct grammatically? and are they equal?”_ but your neither your question nor your title ask that. You question only asks _Which of the following sentences is correct?_ and your title doesn’t add much to that.

Comment: Lastly, when you click on that “Ask question” button you alluded to earlier, there is a yellow box next to the question box. It says: **HOW TO ASK: Provide details. Share your research.** So the guidance provided by @JasonB and NathanT is entirely spot on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid neither of your options is correct! These would be options you could use instead:

> The man offers her a (cup of) coffee.
>
> The man offers to buy her a (cup of) coffee.
>
> The man invites her to drink coffee.
>
> The man invites her for a (cup of) coffee.

Comment: But Grammar checking software such as Grammarly isn't getting an error!

Comment: Then Grammarly, as its name suggests, isn't very good.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence is good (both are ungrammatical). What I think you're trying to say is that he is offering to ***buy*** her a cup of coffee. The fact that she will drink it really has nothing to do with offering to buy it (or make it). I think you're trying to say too much in a few words. In my opinion, just leave out the drinking part entirely. It's obvious that she will drink it if she agrees to his offer.

> The man offers to buy / to make her a coffee.
>
> The man offers her a cup of coffee.