# Why can't we use the Present Perfect tense for dead people?

Tags: tense

> Immanuel Kant has been born in Europe.

I heard that the following sentence is wrong, but why can't we use Present Perfect for a dead person?

Comment: You *can* use present perfect for a dead person: "Immanuel Kant has been dead for a long time." You just can't use it in the way you did, to describe a non-continuous timeframe. Use simple past there: "Immanuel Kant was born in Europe."

Comment: to be born, was born, it only happens once.

Comment: Why is it supposed to be in a continuous timeframe if it doesn't have a participle component (-ing verb)?

Comment: I does have a participle component, but it is the past participle, "been". (*present* participle is the one with "-ing"). The *past* participle is the one you use to make the *present* perfect tense (for the continuing time frame). Sounds crazy, I know.

Comment: It's nothing to do with "continuous" in the sense of the "be x-ing" form of a verb. It's an event that happened in the past and still has present relevance: exactly what that present relevance is depends on the verb. But most things that happen to a person, or that a person does (except dying, as Rubosto says) are no longer relevant once they are dead. Even somebody as influential as Kant.

Comment: As I commented on this same question at [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/using-a-grammatically-incorrect-tense-for-stylistic-effect), I wouldn't even use that construction for people who are still alive—not unless they had just been born and it was used in the form of a birth announcement.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/167291/3395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very unusual to use the singular past participle of "**to be born**" about an individual, a specific individual. Many men *have been born*, but I *was born*. I generally think that "has been born" mostly only works in the 'carry' sense of *to bear*, rather than as a form of *to be born* with its meaning related to *birth*.

There's lots of arguments that people might make as to why, but really, I'm not sure that it isn't just a special case for that one set phrase verb.